# Runtime exception being thrown when including boost::asio headers

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, runtime-error

Given the code . . .

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp> 

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it and link against boost_system-mt, and then run it and get the following output from the console.

> $ ./clientapp
>
> terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl
>
> '   what():  No such file or directory Abort trap

This does not look good. What's up?

Comment: Hmm, I seem to remember seeing that exception being thrown during initialization - but apparently being handled as well. Have you tried actually creating an instance of asio::io_service?

Comment: I suspect your boost libary files are corrupted or something, maybe just try to recompile them?

Comment: @villintehaspam not gone any further yet. Will try

Comment: @Xeo I am lazy and used homebrew to get the boost libs :)

Comment: @villintehaspam it seems you are right. As soon as I do something with an io_service, the message goes away. Still a bit strange though!!

Comment: attach a debugger, where is the exception thrown?

Comment: What platform, boost version and compiler you've used?

Comment: have you tried compiling against .a and not linking against .so just to see if there is some corruption ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the situation is with Homebrew, but I found recently with macports that the boost libraries are buit with the gcc 4.2.1 toolchain. Linking against these with a newer version of gcc (4.7) meant that I saw a similar problem to the one described, e.g. exceptions were thrown but not caught when they should have been. This could be due to the ABI change between gcc 4.2.1 and later versions. Compiling boost yourself with the newer version of the compiler should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Boost::Asio requires pthread too. Try to compile add a -lpthread to the gcc command.